How to force both applications to use the same sequence for generating primary keys in two JPA apps using MySql?
I have a legacy Java application using JPA with a MySQL database. I have access to the source code, but mostly for reference, and I'm not able to make any significant changes or rebuild it from scratch to create a new version.
In the hope of being able to use both applications simultaneously to allow for a gradual migration of functionalities, I'm trying to create a new application, this time using Quarkus. I configured the access, pointed it to the same legacy application database, mapped the entities in the same way they were mapped in the old application, and the queries worked fine.
The problem is that in this legacy application, most of the entities have primary keys declared as auto-increment with the annotation @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO).
With this, when I, for example, (starting from an empty database), initially register a product, its id is set to 1. When I register a customer, its id is saved as 2. Saving a new product after that, the id becomes 3.
Somehow, somewhere in the database, MySQL stores an attribute with this counter, which accumulates the auto-increment of all tables in the system. It seems to be a unique place, for all tables.
It turns out that in the new application with Quarkus using Panache, the same attribute declaration produces a different behavior, generating a number that does not coincide with the last record created by the old application.
I tried to control this via the application itself, in Quarkus, by searching for the last id of the table and manually assigning this value to the object, before saving it. It did save, but it didn't update this attribute that keeps the sequence. So when I went to save a new record in the old application, I get the error "duplicate primary key" because obviously the legacy application didn't "know" about the creation of the new id in the new application.
I would like to know if there is a way for two different applications to feed the same MySQL database without these incompatibilities. I even thought about manually updating this attribute in the new application, but I don't know how to do that.
I've tried adjusting the @GeneratedValue strategy in both applications, but I haven't seen any improvement. Is there a way to force both applications to use the same sequence for generating primary keys?"
If anyone has any other ideas, I would be very grateful.

GenerationType.AUTO (jakarta.ee) does not mean "auto-increment", but "Indicates that the persistence provider should pick an appropriate strategy for the particular database.". I personally find it strange that two different tables use "the same sequence". Anyway, the proper way would most likely be to define an explicit sequence and then bind the primary key of the different tables to that sequence.

Each table in mysql has it's own auto_increment, so it's certainly the apps that are doing something like not choosing IDENTITY strategy when you specify AUTO. Make sure that this thing Quarkus/panache (dunno what those are) will not insert the id column. If the column is to be chosen by mysql, neither app should send an id. Since you get a dup key, they try to set id. Also, have a look at any triggers that might be acting without your knowledge.

in panache doc, they write: "Make your entities extend PanacheEntity: it has an ID field that is auto-generated. If you require a custom ID strategy, you can extend PanacheEntityBase instead and handle the ID yourself." see https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache#how-and-why-we-simplify-hibernate-orm-mappings
